# Angular: unexpected request (ngMockE2E - $httpBackend)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I'm trying to test an Angular directive using Jasmine.

Html looks like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src='/jasmine/jasmine.js'></script>
        <script src='/jasmine/jasmine-html.js'></script>
        <script src='/jasmine/boot.js'></script>
        <script src='/angular/angular.js'></script>
        <script src='/angular/angular-mocks.js'></script>
        <script src='/components/test-directive.js'></script>
        <script src='/app.js'></script>
        <script>
            angular.module('myAppTests', ['myApp', 'ngMockE2E'])
            .run(function($httpBackend){
                $httpBackend.whenGET(/^\/views\//).passThrough();
            });
        </script>
        <script src='/components/test-directive.spec.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

The test directive (/components/test-directive.js)

```
angular.directive('testDirective', function(){
    return {
        templateUrl:'/views/test-directive.html'
    };
});
```

The test file (/components/test-directive.spec.js) looks like this:

```
describe('test directive', function(){
    beforeEach(module('myAppTests'));

    var element, $scope;

    beforeEach(inject(function($compile, $rootScope){
        element = angular.element('<div data-test-directive=""></div>');
        $scope = $rootScope;
        $compile(element)($scope);
        $scope.$digest();
    }));

    it('generates the correct HTML', function(){
        expect(element.html()).toContain('test content');
    });

});
```

And the /views/test-directive.html

```
<p>test content</p>
```

When running the test I get the following error:

```
'Unexpected request: GET /views/test-directive.html'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your filters:

```
$httpBackend.whenGET(/\.html$/).passThrough();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. No luck though. Still throws the same error

Answer (score 0):

When you use any `inject` or `module` in your tests, it implicitly loads ngMock's modules, which includes a mocked $httpBackEnd that doesn't send requests.

One option is to reuse the original $httpBackend.

```
angular.module('myAppTests', ['myApp', 'ngMock'])
  .factory('$httpBackend', function() {
    // use the original $httpBackend instead of the fake backend
    return angular.injector(['ng']).get('$httpBackend');
  });
```